# React.js: Onblur event fires every key press

Tags: reactjs

I have an `onBlur` event which should fire an API upon call

However, my problem is the `onBlur` event gets fired every keypress

I was expecting `onBlur` to fire only when the user changes field or loses focus on that field

```
const handleOnBlur = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("ChangePasswordPage - handleOnBlur oldPassword >>> ", oldPassword)
    PasswordService.validateOldPassword(oldPassword)
  });

return (
<input type="text" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" className="form-control" 
                value={oldPassword} maxLength="20" 
                onChange={e => setOldPassword(e.target.value)}
                onBlur={ handleOnBlur() }    
            />
)
```

Also, what's the difference if I trigger the event on `useEffect` hook? Seems like `useEffect` also works like onkeypress or every time that certain state is changed

TIA

Comment: Your `onBlur` should be `onBlur={ handleOnBlur}`     instead of `onBlur={ handleOnBlur() }`

Comment: Wow. Didn't know that. Mind explaining the difference? And when to use the other one. It works fine now, thanks!

Comment: The difference is that when you add parentheses, you call the function right away and you pass the **result** of the function, instead the function itstelf.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On blur will be called everytime you are redering the component, since you are doing `onBlur={ handleOnBlur() }` , this syntax will lead handleOnBlur function to be called everytime. Since , it is a function call.

Here you need callback, So it should be , `onBlur={ () => handleOnBlur() }` or `onBlur={ handleOnBlur }`

So you're having problem of handleOnBlur getting called on every keypress.

Try this,

```
  const handleOnBlur = () => {
        console.log("ChangePasswordPage - handleOnBlur oldPassword >>> ", oldPassword)
        PasswordService.validateOldPassword(oldPassword)
   };

return (
<input type="text" id="oldPassword" name="oldPassword" className="form-control" 
                value={oldPassword} maxLength="20" 
                onChange={e => setOldPassword(e.target.value)}
                onBlur={ () => handleOnBlur() }  {/* this is how you should call a callback function */}     
            />
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to add on my question, what if the user just clicked the field then left? How can I avoid it being undefined? Should I use `useEffect` instead? Or onblur is the best for this job.

Comment: To answer this i would first like to know., When exactly to you want to fire the api? After what changes?

Comment: I couldn't understand your question. But if you want to see if user has not added anything in input field. And he left input and onBlur fired. So i that case you can add a check inside handleOnBlur function before firing api. 

You can check 
if(e.target.value){
---> fire api
}

Comment: After the user has fully inputted the old password, then I would fire the api to validate it.

Comment: you can use onBlur={ (e) => handleOnBlur(e) }

handleOnBlur = (e) => {
if(e.target.value){
/* fire api */
}
}

Comment: I'm getting undefined value of `e`

Comment: Sorry was just a syntax error on my part. Why did you not use state in this scenario though?

Comment: why do you want to use useState? In this case you are anyways getting the value through onBlur. useState is used to set a changing value which you might want to use later in your app.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-cloud-vxpiv?file=/src/App.js 

for firing api you can check this.

Comment: Moreover, i'm still not so much clear about your use case, So that i can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, just replace:

```
onBlur={ handleOnBlur() }
```

with:

```
onBlur={ handleOnBlur }
```

Basically, onBlur must point to a function, not to the result of a function